# Which files should I include when I wish to deploy a library with my project using node.js?

Tags: deployment, node.js

I used npm to install most of my dependent libraries. Now I would like to add these libraries to my working directory so that another computer can directly run it w/o manually downloading and installing these files.
I have seen many projects on github do this.

How should this be done? And which files should I include? Most of my libraries are in `/usr/local/lib/node/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to run a stand-alone node.js application is your application code and the node binary executable--typically found under /usr/local/bin--as it already contains all of the "native" modules. (See below for a list.) If your application requires other libraries than these, you'd need to provide them as part of your application.

If you choose to deploy your application to a server using npm, the method outlined below by @Raynos will work nicely.

On the other hand if you choose to deploy your application to a server via git or as an archive, you'll need to provide all of the libraries required by your application as well as their dependencies.

One way to do this is to install/copy all required libraries under the 'node-modules' directory in your application's home directory.

As of Node@0.4.7, the native modules include: assert, buffer, child_process, console, constants, crypto, dgram, dns, events, freelist, fs, http, https, module, net, os, path, querystring, readline, repl, stream, string_decoder, sys, timers, tls, tty, url, util and vm.

See http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/modules.html for further information.

Comment: All the files from the libraries? Isn't that too big? What I would like to know is which files are essential, and which are only source(eg. c-source).

Comment: Well, as I pointed out, the node binary _already includes_ all the "native" modules (assert,buffer,etc.). You'd only need to include any _additional_ modules your application required.

Comment: You mean all the files of additional modules? Or a subset is enough?

Comment: You would only need to include those libraries your application requires.  So, if your application uses 'express', you'd need to include it as well as any of its dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Create a package.json file that states what your dependencies are then use `npm link` to install from that package file.

example package file :

```
{
    "name": "Inventory-System",
    "description": "Manage Inventory web app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Raynos",
    "dependencies": {
        "now": "0.5.3",
        "backbone": "0.3.2",
        "cradle": "0.5.5",
        "supervisor": "0.1.2",
        "less": "1.0.41",
        "ejs": "0.4.1"
    }
}
```

This allows you to declaratively define your dependancies then installing your library because as simple as `npm link`.

You can also go further and publish your own library through `npm` then just call `npm install myLibrary` on another computer.

Comment: Sorry, but I wouldn't like to publish my app on npm. Are you saying that `npm link` works by installing all dependencies in package.json?

Comment: @TiansHUo If you create a package.json file and state your dependencies. You can then call `npm link` in that directory, it will look in your package and automatically install all your dependencies for you.